# Where to set -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting errors from the durable task plugin when I run my pipeline dsl jenkins job.

The error message suggests that I should use:

```
-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300
```

This is the error I get:

```
\workspace\ne-sw-manifest_master-5ZF5EWBP7EVBXEBF6AS3C6UQLIXLCS3HRKYND6TPQAPIKZPFBDLQ@tmp\durable-252b3bfd
(JENKINS-48300: if on a laggy filesystem, consider -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300)
```

**I am not sure where to set this property.**

I tried on Jenkins master -> Configure system -> Global properties -> Environment variables:

```
Name:org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL
        Value:300
```

But, I am not sure if this is the right place to add this property OR if it has come into effect.

Also, I haven't restarted the master or slave.

My jenkins set-up is Linux master (Jenkins ver. 2.107.1) and Linux and Windows Slaves.

My build is on a Windows slave (physical machine)

Comment: That is a system property level for the JVM, so should be specified in whatever your launcher's mechanism for that is. You could change it at runtime through something like the Jenkins *Script Console*, but that won't persist through runs and might not even work depending on how the plugin is implemented.

Answer (score 13):

**option 1:**
Add in your pipeline

`script {
System.setProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL", "3800");
 }`

after Running the approve the script in security settings at Manage Jenkins – In-**process Script approval**.

**Option 2:**

go to Manage Jenkins -> Script Console
and run

```
System.setProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL", "3800");
```

Comment: Option 2 is valid, but keep in mind that these are static properties being updated from that property, and that they are set on first usage, and kept in memory as such. So, if the static value is set, setting system property is useless. In order to make Option 2 valid, you need to set value after fresh Jenkins restart, before first build. You can use: org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL directly in console to check value after the change (will be printed below). If you print it before setting System property, it will not be changed after.

Answer (score 5):

[This CloudBees article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-) explains how to set Jenkins Java arguments.

**Note:** you'll need to restart your Jenkins instance.

**Edit:** As per [sirch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067372/where-to-set-dorg-jenkinsci-plugins-durabletask-bourneshellscript-heartbeat-che/50100551?noredirect=1#comment88173437_50100551), I'm copying here the instructions for RedHat and Debian distro's.

## Debian / Ubuntu based Linux distributions

If your configuration file is under `/etc/default/` look for the argument `JAVA_ARGS`. It should look something like this:

`JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"`

Then, add the arguments:

`JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"`

## RedHat Linux based distributions

If your configuration file is under `/etc/sysconfig/` look for the argument `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`. It should look something like this:

`JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"`

Then, add the arguments:

`JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not straightforward to restart out jenkins master (approvals etc). I noticed that I can amend/append the JVM options for slave agents under the node configuration in jenkins. I added it there but as my jenkins slave is set-up as a windows service, I have run into another problem where JVM option added here don't reflect in jenkins-slave.xml

Comment: I have gone ahead and added this JVM option under, node configuration->JVM options and restarted the slave service. I can now see org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300 on the slave's System Information page in jenkins. Do I still need to set this on the master as well? My build is tied to this slave, so will not run elsewhere.

Comment: Im unable to follow the link you mention. Its much better to paste the info here, and links may move.

Answer (score 0):

set it either

`JAVA_OPTS`

or

`JNLP_PROTOCOL_OPTS`

which will be included in `jenkins slave` Startup Options